# Angular target.getAttribute() check null condition

Tags: javascript, angular

I was having some problem with Angular. I am trying to set different value accordingly. Below as my code:

```
 console.log("JJJJJJJ " + target.getAttribute("timingId"));
        console.log("KKKKKKKKK " + target.getAttribute("index"));
        if(target.getAttribute("timingId") != null){
          console.log("INSIDE ORI SET");
          this.timingId = target.getAttribute("timingId");
        } else {
          console.log("INSIDE INDEX SET");
          this.timingId = target.getAttribute("index");
        }
        console.log("HAHAHAHAHAHAH " + this.timingId);
```

What I am trying to do is check in timindId from getAttribute(), if it is not null, then set it. If it is null, getAttribute() from another field then set it. My console as per following:

```
JJJJJJJ null
KKKKKKKKK 1
INSIDE ORI SET
HAHAHAHAHAHAH null
```

I am not sure why when it is detected as null, it will not go into the else statement and set the value. Any ideas?

**EDITED**

```
console.log(typeof target.getAttribute("timingId"));
        console.log("JJJJJJJ " + target.getAttribute("timingId"));
        console.log("KKKKKKKKK " + target.getAttribute("index"));
        if(target.getAttribute("timingId") != null || target.getAttribute("timingId") != "null"){
          console.log("INSIDE ORI SET");
          this.timingId = target.getAttribute("timingId");
        } else {
          console.log("INSIDE INDEX SET");
          this.timingId = target.getAttribute("index");
        }
        console.log("HAHAHAHAHAHAH " + this.timingId);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that the value of your attribute is the string "null"?

Comment: @AlbertoRivera Just tried to add in additional condition check on string 'null' but it does not work also

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(typeof target.getAttribute("timingId"))`?

Comment: @AlbertoRivera That printed out as string but it is still went inside the if statement instead of else

Comment: The `if` check is incorrect. If timingId is string "null", it will pass the first check and it won't evaluate the second one. It should be `&&` instead of `||`. I will post this as my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for "null" as a string in the `if` statement.

```
const timingId = target.getAttribute("timingId")
if (timingId != null && timingId !== "null") {
   this.timingId = timingId
} else {
   this.timingId = target.getAttribute("index");
}
```